# Is it necessary to do self-consistent calculation after structure optimization?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, band-structure, materials-design

When calculating the band structure of a material, I have been told that at first, I need to do structure optimization to get a stationary structure(**1st step**), and then keep the atoms' position fixed, do a self-consistent calculation to get the band structure(**2nd step**). But if I am doing this job with VASP, self-consistent field calculation of the electrons is included in the loop when optimizing the structure. The only difference is at the first step of optimizing structures, the atoms' position is variant, but when getting to convergence, I am guessing the atoms' positions don't vary too much actually 
My question is:
Is there a difference between the charge density of the 1st step and 2nd step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The procedure that takes more time to finish is the geometry optimization (in each step there are self-consistence field calculations).

There are properties that can not be calculated at the same time (all in one step) or you need to know more information about how to calculate it. For example, to calculate the DOS, you need to know the band structure to then, select the energy interval.

Answering your question: *Is there a significant difference between the charge density of the 1st step and 2nd step?* No.

Comment: So after structure optimization, I don’t need to keep the atoms’ position fixed and do self-consistent calculation again. I could just do non self consistent calculation to get band structure?

Comment: No, for each property, you need to do self-consistent field (SCF) calculation. But if your code save the SCF data, you can just load it and use it. Also, you have to remember to replace the atom's positions in your input file with the optimized ones.

Comment: But the standard procedure is 1-structure optimization,2-SCF calculation,3-non-SCF calculation to get band structure. I am actually wondering if I could just do 1 and 3. I just don’t understand why all the lecture and tutorials  recommend three steps.

Comment: Often you want a dense k-point grid in the SCF (step 2) prior to step 3 to get a smooth band structure (or what ever quantity you are computing). But performing the structure optimization with a dense grid is expensive. So separating step 1 and 2 is mainly for computational reasons.

Comment: @Fabian, I checked the vasp wiki. it says: Since the charge density written to the file CHGCAR is not the self-consistent charge density for the positions on the CONTCAR file, do not perform a bandstructure calculation (ICHARG=11) directly after a dynamic simulation (IBRION=0).  Here is hyperlink:https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/CHGCAR

Comment: @Fabian, but according to my result, the CHGCAR is consistent with the positions in CONTCAR.

Comment: @Jack You should read the entire page. The paragraphe before says "For dynamic simulation (IBRION=0), the charge density on the file is the predicted charge density for the next step [...] For static calculations and relaxations (IBRION=-1,1,2) the written charge density is the self-consistent charge density for the last step and might be used e.g. for accurate band-structure calculations."